# Angular 6: View not showing update after patch

Tags: angular, typescript, view, httpclient, patch

I have project of users and courses, and I update the database if the user watched lessons or finished quizzes. After a patch I can see the database update correctly, but when I call get after the update to fetch the new data, the data stay the same as before the update. Only if I refresh the page I see the changes.

**course-play.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Routes, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';

import { ICourse, IUnit, IVideo, IQuiz } from '../course';
import { CourseService } from '../course.service';
import { UserProgressService } from '../../users/user-progress.service';

export class CoursePlayComponent implements OnInit {
  // configurations 
    errorMessage: string;
    course: ICourse;
    public current: IVideo;
    currentUnitQuiz: IQuiz;
    courseId: number;
    totalLessons: number;   // all lessons in the course
    totalQuizzes: number;   // all quizzes in the course
    
    // ... more configs not important for now ...
  
  constructor(private courseService: CourseService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private router: Router,
      private userProgressService: UserProgressService) {
        userProgressService.connectUser();
       }

  ngOnInit() {
      // ...
 
      // save this course id from course-detail and get http request from the service
      this.courseId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("courseId"));
      this.getCourse(this.courseId);
    }
    
      // Get course detail by id
  getCourse(id: number) {
      this.courseService.getCourse(id).subscribe(
          course => {
            this.course = course;

            // .. more code here ..

          },
          error  => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
      }
      
    // calculate which quiz is now and save it to currentUnitQuiz
    getQuiz(currentUnitPosition: number) { 
      // ...
    }
    
    // calculate which lesson is now and save it to current
    getCurrent(unitPosition: number, lessonPosition: number) {
      // ...
    }
    
    // .. more functions ...
    

    // EventEmitter from course-lesson component and send the data I need to update
    watched(state) {
      this.userProgressService.addToCompletedLessons(this.course.id, this.current.id,
      this.totalLessons, this.totalQuizzes);
    }
  
    // EventEmitter from course-quiz component and send the data I need to update
    finishedQuiz(state) {
      this.userProgressService.addToCompletedQuizzes(this.course.id, this.currentUnitQuiz.id,
      this.totalLessons, this.totalQuizzes);
    }
    
 }
```

**play.html**

```html
<mat-sidenav-container fullscreen *ngIf="course">
  <mat-sidenav class="app-sidenav">
  <!-- more code that's not important for now  -->
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-toolbar id="appToolbar">
    <!-- .... -->
  </mat-toolbar>

    <div class="body">
      <course-lesson *ngIf="showLesson == true" [lessonId]="current?.id" [lessonName]="current?.name" [lessonData]="current?.data" [totalLessons]="totalLessons" (clicked)="watched($event)"></course-lesson>
      <quiz-course *ngIf="showQuiz == true" [quiz]="currentUnitQuiz" [minCorrectAnswers]="currentUnitQuiz?.min_correct_answers" (passed)="finishedQuiz($event)"></quiz-course>

        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**user-progress.service**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, groupBy } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';

import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { AuthUserService } from './auth-user.service';
import { IUser, IUserCourses } from './user';

export class UserProgressService {
      private user: IUser;
      private errorMessage: string;

      constructor(private authUser: AuthUserService, private userService: UserService) { }
      
      // get user from local store
      connectUser() {
        this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      }
      
      // update user after changes - call the backend again for GET
      updateUser() {
        this.userService.getUser(this.user.id).subscribe(
          user => {
            this.user = user;
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));

            console.log(this.user); // <--- print the old data, before changes
          },
          error  => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
      }
      
      // update complete lessons of a certain course
      addToCompletedLessons(course_id: number, lesson_id: number, totalLessons: number,
      totalQuizzes: number) {
        let userCourses = this.user.user_courses;
        let userLessons;

       // .. actions to know if we need to update or the lesson is already in database

        // add the lesson to database
        const updatedLessons = userLessons + `,${lesson_id}`;
        this.userService.updateCompletedLessons(this.user.id, course_id,
        updatedLessons).subscribe(
          () => {
              console.log("PATCH call successful value returned in body");
          },
          error  => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );

        // get from backend updated data
        this.updateUser();
      }

      // update complete lessons of a certain course
      addToCompletedQuizzes(course_id: number, quiz_id: number, totalLessons: number,
      totalQuizzes: number) {
        let userCourses = this.user.user_courses;
        let userQuizzes;

        // .. actions to know if we need to update or the quiz is already in database

        // add the quiz to the list
        const updatedQuizzes = userQuizzes + `,${quiz_id}`;
        this.userService.updateCompletedQuizzes(this.user.id, course_id,
        updatedQuizzes).subscribe(
          () => {
              console.log("PATCH call successful value returned in body");
          },
          error  => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );

        // get from backend updated data
        this.updateUser();
      }
```

**user.service**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, groupBy, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { IUser, IUserCourses } from './user';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private url = 'http://localhost:3000/users';


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {  }

  // Get Single user by id. will 404 if id not found
  getUser(id: number): Observable<IUser> {
    const detailUrl = `${this.url}/${id}` + '.json';

    return this.http.get<IUser>(detailUrl)
        .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  // call mark_lesson_as_completed in backend
  updateCompletedLessons(user_id: number, course_id: number, param: any): Observable<any> {
    const userUrl = `${this.url}/${user_id}` + '.json';
    let body = JSON.stringify({
      course_id: course_id,
      completed_lessons: param
    });

    return this.http.patch(userUrl, body, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => console.log(`updated user ${user_id} with this entry: ${param}`)),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  // call mark_quiz_as_completed in backend
  updateCompletedQuizzes(user_id: number, course_id: number, param: any): Observable <any> {
    const userUrl = `${this.url}/${user_id}` + '.json';
    let body = JSON.stringify({
      course_id: course_id,
      completed_quizzes: param
    });

    return this.http.patch(userUrl, body, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => console.log(`updated user ${user_id} with this entry: ${param}`)),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  // // Handle Any Kind of Errors
  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {

    // A client-side or network error occured. Handle it accordingly.
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.error('An error occured:', error.error.message);
    }

    // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
    // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong.
    else {
      console.error(
        'Backend returned code ${error.status}, ' +
        'body was ${error.error}');
    }

    // return an Observable with a user-facing error error message
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happend; please try again later.');
  }
}
```

Comment: in your `play.hrml` file, you're referring to a variable called `showLesson`. Is that the variable that you need to be changed when your database is updated?

Comment: yes, I update it in getQuiz and getCurrent, and I call those in the menu when I click item in the menu. I see the data but it's the old one. For example I did a quiz that I don't have in the database, press submit, the submit activate the finished function in course-play which activate the addToCompletedQuizzes in userProgress, which activate the update function and called the HttpClient service but the data didn't change

Answer (score 0):

I solved it after one of my friends explain it to me.
It appears that the PATCH and any request to add or edit the database taking time, and in the mean while the program continue to do other things, so the update function where I fetch the new data from the database was called before the PATCH request finished.

what I did is I called the update function inside the subscribe, like that:

```js
        this.userService.updateCompletedLessons(this.user.id, course_id, updatedLessons).subscribe(
          () => {
              console.log("PATCH call successful value returned in body");
              // get from backend updated data
              this.updateUser();
          },
          error  => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
```